# Mantle.h file not found

Tags: objective-c, cocoapods

I am pretty new here/to iOS.

I am trying to fix up something my buddy was building and had left...
I have been trying to compile this for the last 2 days.

Hoping to get some insight into what I am missing.

I am receiving 'Mantle/Mantle.h' file not found.
I have installed cocoapods, from what I understand thats what Mantle is.

I keep receiving an error for file not found, however I am not sure is it something to install or drop a file somewhere...?

My podfile has mantle listed... I am not sure what am I missing. Some assistance or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you send the screen shot of your link command error?

Comment: resolved the issue, turns out the Pod and framework files were left out for when we opened the project for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm you have added all pods in all targets:
There was two targets for my projects `'MyTestApp Dist'` and `'MyTestApp'`

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '9.0'

def myPods
    pod 'Mantle'
end

target 'MyTestApp Dist' do
    myPods
end

target 'MyTestApp' do
  myPods
end
```