# Mantle/Mantle.h' file not found when using cocoapods

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, mantle

Mantle/Mantle.h' file not found when using cocoapods.

I have tried the different version, it did not work.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What's your podFile? Did you opened the xcworkspace and not the xcodeproj? Does Mantle appear in Pods folders of your project?

Comment: Please find answer for the same issue: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44299513/2226399](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44299513/2226399)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the device data, and build again.

The device data in: 
/Users/{whoami}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/